# How to use Where clause with DataSet in C# Win form

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, bindingsource, tableadapter

I use adgv (advanced filter) to my dataGridView with DataBindingSource

```
computerDataSet is my Dataset

computerBindingSource is my BindingSourse

and computerTableAdapter is my TableAdapter
```

In my Load form it creats this one to load data from my table "Computer"

```
this.computerTableAdapter.Fill(this.computerDataSet.Computer);
```

But I have departmentId in my Computer table "deptId" and I want to use "Where Clause..."
I want to put condition but I don't know how to do it.
In linq I would do like this

```
var computers = db.Computer.Where(x =>x.deptId == departmentId).Tolist(); // I have value of departmentId
```

But How can I put like Where condition in this code

```
this.computerTableAdapter.Fill(this.computerDataSet.Computer);
```

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: You need to change the adapter `SelectCommand`

Comment: @Charlieface , thank you for your response. Please I am new for this kind of staff and I dont know what you mean to change SelectCommand. Cna you please write me some code what and how do you mean?

Comment: No I can't because I have no idea where that adapter comes from, you have provided no code for it

Comment: @Charlieface . it creats it' self when I create connection with BindingSourse

Answer (score 0):

Advanced DatagridView Tasks I clicked "Add Query" and Created a new query
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You open the DataSet file where the tableadapter lives, right click on it and choose Add Query. You can add any number of queries to a tableadapter